# ¿Cómo generar un barplot de dos factores independientes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo dos `dataframes` distintos dónde solo me interesa una columna del tipo `factor`. Por ejemplo:

```
set.seed(1)
levels <- c("0 to 4", "5 to 7", "8 to 11", "12 to 17", "18 to 19", "20 to 24")
myfactor <- factor(levels,levels=levels)
a <- data.frame(Q1=sample(myfactor, 100, replace = TRUE))
b <- data.frame(Q1=sample(myfactor, 100, replace = TRUE))

head(a)
            Q1
    1   5 to 7
    2  8 to 11
    3 12 to 17
    4 20 to 24
    5   5 to 7
    6 20 to 24
```

La idea es contar las cantidades por cada `factor` y realizar un `barplot` combinado para  poder ver los niveles `Q1` apilados y así compararlos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partiendo de `a` y `b` como están definidos en la pregunta. No requiere `gridExtra` pero sí todo el `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(a, b, .id = "Origen") %>% 
  mutate(Origen = recode(Origen, "1" = "a", "2" = "b")) %>%  
  count(Origen, Q1) %>% 
  group_by(Q1) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>%
  gather(clave, valor, n, prop) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Q1, y = valor, fill = Origen)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    facet_grid(clave~., scales = "free") #scales = "free" para manejar dos escalas en el mismo gráfico.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

#### Usando gráficas de R base

El quid de la cuestión es transformar los dos `data.frames` en uno solo con una nueva variable que indique el `Origen` es decir el `data.frame` en cuestión. Lo siguiente es crear la columna `Origen` e inicializarla, luego simplemente unimos ambos `data.frame` mediante `rbind()`:

```
a$Origen <- "a"
b$Origen <- "b"
newdf <- rbind(a,b)
```

Ahora, para usar las gráficas base, nos conviene armar una tabla de contingencia mediante `table()` de la siguiente forma:

```
bartable <- table(newdf$Origen, newdf$Q1)
bartable
   0 to 4 5 to 7 8 to 11 12 to 17 18 to 19 20 to 24
  a     11     16      25       13       21       14
  b     11     18      17       23       13       18
```

Usando un `barplot()` la solución resulta muy sencilla:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
# x Cantidad
barplot(bartable, legend = row.names(bartable))
# x Proporción
barplot(prop.table(bartable, 2) * 100, legend = row.names(bartable))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Usando ggplot

Con los datos anteriores, y sin necesidad de pasar por un `table()` podemos hacer:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(
    ggplot(data = newdf, mapping = aes(fill=Origen, x=Q1)) + 
        geom_bar( stat="count"), 
    ggplot(data = newdf, mapping = aes(fill=Origen, x=Q1)) + 
        geom_bar(position="fill"),
    nrow = 2)
```

Aquí estamos creando un `geom_bar()` con la particularidad que usamos una función para generar los valores `y` y que en el primer caso es `count`. Para lograr las barras por porcentaje usamos el parámetro `position="fill"`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: en ambos ejemplo se muestra las versiones con valores absolutos y por porcentaje.

Comment: Muy elegante el gráfico con R base. Si no diera tanto trabajo ajustar `par()` una y otra vez...